# Mysql Friend database table model

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I currently have a chat & users table. The chat will be for a user to message another but only if you are their friend. Although it currently is public. How ever I will be using the friend table to determine if those two users have a link.
And the users table consists of: id, email, password, firstname, lastname, age... etc. id being auto increment.
How would I go about creating a friend table?

Comment: A table with two userids should do it for the most basic.

Comment: Such as: id, my_id, friend_id
Although how would you determine the link between the two?

Comment: How would you not? Use a join to join users table and friends table on the userid of the user you're looking at, of course. (Find an SQL tutorial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a link table "friend_links"

columns: friend_id_1 | friend_id_2

(also put a unique constraint on friend_id_1 + friend_id_2, and make them both foreign keys that refer to the user_id in your users table )

Every time someone becomes a friend of someone else, you add their ids to the table.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `friend_links` (friend_id_1, friend_id_2) VALUES (5,10);
```

To find out if two users are friends:

```
SELECT FROM `friend_links` WHERE (friend_id_1 = 5 AND friend_id_2 =10) OR (friend_id_1 = 10 AND friend_id_2 = 5);
```

If you get more than 0 results, they are friends.